# Auto Scroll a div without moving the whole page with velocity.js

Tags: c#, jquery, autoscroll, velocity.js

I would like to make an auto scroll across within a div but my codes scroll the whole page. How could I do so that it only scrolls in the div?

Codes:

```
<div class="banner">
    div class="logo"></div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.logo{
    background-image: url(image.png) center no-repeat;
}

#container{
    width: 1800px;
    height: 1050px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

In JQuery:

```
var scrollWidth = $("#container").width();
var scrollHeight = $("#container").height();
$("#container").velocity("scroll", {
    axis: "x",
    duration: 10000,
    offset: scrollWidth 
})
.velocity("scroll", {
    axis: "y",
    duration: 10000,
    offset: scrollHeight 
});
```

The codes I have provided above will scroll together with the .banner, but I want to fixed the position when auto scroll the #container div. I'm using velocity.js to make the auto scroll.

Answer (score 0):

If you are scrolling inside `#container` you must provide `container` property on your velocity animation, check [Julian Shapiro demo](http://codepen.io/julianshapiro/pen/kBuEi)

Another solution could be set banner's position to fixed instead of absolute